# Animate objects on canvas with an array

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

Been trying to animate an object on canvas by putting it in an array but it wont seem to work.

Only have one object drawn at the moment but the thought is to add several more objects to the canvas hence the array.

Is there something wrong with the functions im using to draw and animate the object?

```js
var draw;
     function Canvas(canvas, ctx) {
      this.canvas = canvas;
      this.ctx = ctx;
     }
     function Direction(x, y) {
       this.x = x;
       this.y = y;
      
     }
     function Measures(cW, cH, radius, hR, degree, dirX, dirY, degree) {
       this.cW = cW;
       this.cH = cH;
       this.radius = radius;
       this.hR = hR;
       this.dirX = dirX;
       this.dirY = dirY;
       this.degree = degree;
     }
      
     function Drawing(cW, cH, width, height, radius, hR, color) {
      this.cW = canvas.width;
      this.cH = canvas.height;
      this.width = width;
         this.height = height;
         this.radius = height / 2;
         this.hR = width - this.radius;  
         this.color = color;
    
         
         
         this.render = function() {
         ctx.fillStyle = this.color;
      ctx.strokeStyle = this.color; 
      ctx.lineWidth = 1;
         ctx.save();
      ctx.translate(this.x, this.y);
      ctx.rotate(this.degree * Math.PI / 180);
      ctx.translate(-this.x, -this.y);
      ctx.beginPath();
      ctx.moveTo(this.x, this.y);
      ctx.lineTo(x + this.hR, this.y);
      ctx.arc(this.x + this.hR, this.y + this.radius, this.radius, - Math.PI / 2, Math.PI / 2);
      ctx.lineTo(this.x, this.y + height);
      ctx.closePath();
      ctx.fill();
      ctx.stroke();
      ctx.restore();
            }
         
         this.move = function(multiplier) {
         var multiplier = 2;
         var borders = 5;
      if(this.dirX > 0 && this.x > this.cW - borders - width){
             this.degree = 90; 
             this.dirX = 0; 
             this.dirY = 1;
             this.x = cW - borders;
         }
         else if(this.dirY > 0 && this.y > this.cH - borders - width){
             this.degree = 180; 
             this.dirX = -1; 
             this.dirY = 0;
             this.y = this.cH - borders;
         }
         else if(this.dirX < 0 && this.x < borders + width){
             this.degree = -90; 
             this.dirX = 0; 
             this.dirY = -1;
             this.x = borders;
         }
         else if(this.dirY < 0  && this.y < borders + width){
             this.degree = 0; 
             this.dirX = 1; 
             this.dirY = 0;
             this.y = borders;
         }
         
         this.x += this.dirX * multiplier;
         this.y += this.dirY * multiplier;
             
            
            this.render();
           }
        
      }
      function animate() {
      ctx.clearRect(0, 0, this.cW, this.cH); 
      draw.forEach(function(object) {
        object.render(2);
        });
      requestAnimationFrame(animate);
      }
    
      function init() {
        this.canvas = document.getElementById("my_canvas");
        this.ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
        this.degree = Math.PI / 2;  
     
        
        draw = [];
        draw.push(new Drawing(5, 5, 80, 60, new Direction(1,0), "#E5E5E5"));
        
        animate();
      
      }
      
  window.onload = init;
    
    </script>
```

```html
<canvas id="my_canvas" width="1000" height="800" style="background-color:#33CC33"></canvas>
```

Comment: ctx.lineTo(this.x + this.hR, this.y); put this instead of this  ctx.lineTo(x + this.hR, this.y);

Comment: Didnt make any difference but thanks, didnt notice that miss :)

Comment: You have a move function, but where are you calling it?

Comment: function animate() {
      ctx.clearRect(0, 0, this.cW, this.cH); 
      draw.forEach(function(object) {
        object.move(2);
        });
      requestAnimationFrame(animate);
      }

Comment: Where should i call the move function?